# How to get the calling number in Phonegap on Android?

Tags: android, cordova

Is it possible to get the number when someone is calling me from Phonegap app?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While you may get a response, many users ignore questions that look like they can be answered with a simple web search. To improve your question: add the relevant code that you have tried (or any technical references to what you want to do), why it doesn't work, and any errors that you received. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No. Phonegap doesn't provide an [event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html) for this.